# Density Gaussian distribution

Tags: matlab

I generate a cloud of point with a Gaussian density.

```
X = [x_centroid,y_centroid] + sigma*randn(number_points, 2);
```

Then, I plot the distribution :

```
D = hist3(X);
```

My question is that I would prove that the distribution is well a Gaussian distribution. Maybe by plotting on the same graph the theoretical distribution, but with hist3, can you help me ?

Maybe there is an other way mathematically ? (Coul be very good to test the both way)

Thanks

Comment: Sure, what's preventing you from plotting a theoretical Gaussian?

Comment: I haven't found how to do it in 3 dimensions. Do you know how to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to plot a real distribution you can find the code in the following:

```
 xmin = -100;
 xmax = 100;
 ymin = -100;
 ymax = 100;
 step = 0.1;
 sigma = 5;
 mu = [0.5; 0.5]
 covMatrix = [sigma 0; 0 sigma];
 invCov = inv(covMatrix);
 detCov = det(covMatrix);
 [X,Y] = meshgrid(xmin:step:xmax, ymin:step:ymax);

 % equation of multivariate normal distribution
 Z = exp(((X-mu(1))*invCov(1,1) + (Y-mu(2))*invCov(2,1)).*(X-mu(1)) + ((X-mu(1))*invCov(1,2) + (Y-mu(2))*invCov(2,2)).*(Y-mu(2))/sqrt(2*pi*detCov)

 % plot the distribution
 mesh(X,Y,Z);
```

You can find the details of multivariate normal distribution in [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution).

Also, you can use `ezplot` to plot the distribution.